# Auto indent all code without ctrl+A in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, auto-indent

One can auto indent all code in a .m file by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. However, this requires selecting all code which in my MATLAB IDE (R2011a, Linux, with Windows Shortcuts) moves the cursor to the end of the .m file. I then have to scroll back to where I was working.

**Is there a way to autoindent an entire .m file without moving the cursor to the end of the file?**

Comment: Do not scroll back, just do `ctrl+Home` to go to the beginning. Or if the code is too long, do not select all the code, just select the section you are working and then auto indent it with `ctrl+I`!!

Comment: Humm. I feel selecting the lines of interest might be a bit of a hassle (admittedly less than having to come back and find my place though). I think `ctrl+Home` might work even if it only gets part of t he file. Thanks!

Comment: Remember which line you were on, then `ctrl+g` after you did the indent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many modern IDEs and text editors, including MATLAB, support the keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> for the "Go to line #" command.

I would therefore suggest simply remembering the line number you were on, and just coming back to it using the aforementioned shortcut after applying the indent the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically indent the file from the REPL.

```matlab
t=matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
t.smartIndentContents;
```